# Firebug script reload

Tags: firebug

Is there a way to reload script in Firebug? I'm getting the old script continuously instead of newly saved one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try clearing the cache of your browser, to force it to re-download the *(new version of the)* script from the server.

While developing and testing CSS / JS, it might be interesting to disable caching of static files, either by disabling cache in the browser, or making sure the server doesn't indicate the client they should cache.